# What is the logic behind xs:date datatype in xsd schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to know how the xs:date datatype is defined in W3C xsd schema. Is there anyway to find it? (Not how to use xs:date in my xsd schema)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you simply looking for the spec? The current spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. I want this spec only. I want to know which regular expression they used for this xs:date.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am able to see the dateLexicalRep but where to view "Constraint: Day-of-month Representations" code

Comment: You mean this rule? Constraint: Day-of-month Values
The ·day· value must be no more than 30 if ·month· is one of 4, 6, 9, or 11, no more than 28 if ·month· is 2 and ·year· is not divisible by 4, or is divisible by 100 but not by 400, and no more than 29 if ·month· is 2 and ·year· is divisible by 400, or by 4 but not by 100.

Comment: Yeah @MichaelKay this rule only. I want to view logic how this rule was implemented.

Comment: Implemented in which schema processor? Every XSD implementation will implement it in its own language. Remember xs:date is a primitive type.

Comment: You can find Saxon's implementation here: https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-CE/blob/master/src/client/net/sf/saxon/ce/value/GDateValue.java (method isValidDate).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for your patience. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the documentation? http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date